# Struggling to get 'get absolute url' to work (Python - Django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Once a user had logged into my site he could write a post and update it.

Then I was making progress in adding functionality which allowed people to make comments. I was at the stage where I could add comments from the back end and they would be accurately displayed on the front end.

Now when I try and update posts I get an error message.

I assume it is because there is a foreign key linking the comments class to the post class. I tried Googling the problem and looking on StackOverflow but I wasn't entirely convinced the material I was reading was remotely related to my problem. I am struggling to fix the issue because I barely even understand / know what the issue is.

[image]

**models.py**

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**views.py**

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
template_name = 'post_detail.html'

comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=pk ,active=True)
post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
new_comment = None
# Comment posted
if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():

        # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        # Assign the current post to the comment
        new_comment.post = post
        # Save the comment to the database
        new_comment.save()
else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()

return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                       'comments': comments,
                                       'new_comment': new_comment,
                                       'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have no field in your model `Comment` called slug (aka `SlugField`) so it's not going to work.
The save method should be defined in the class also - see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods). You also don't need the `get_absolute_url` under `save()` either.